# Python Pillow: Add transparent gradient to an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to add transparent gradient to an image like on the image below , I tried this:

```
def test(path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
        im = im.convert('RGBA')
    width, height = im.size
    gradient = Image.new('L', (width, 1), color=0xFF)
    for x in range(width):
        gradient.putpixel((0 + x, 0), x)
    alpha = gradient.resize(im.size)
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    im.save('out.png', 'PNG')
```

But with this I added only white gradient. How can I change color of gradient and control size of gradient.

I need like the following but without text.

[image: this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code actually does what it says it does. However, if your image background is not black but white, then the image will appear lighter. The following code merges the original image with a black image, such that you have the dark gradient effect irrespective of background.

```
def test(path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
        im = im.convert('RGBA')
    width, height = im.size
    gradient = Image.new('L', (width, 1), color=0xFF)
    for x in range(width):
        gradient.putpixel((x, 0), 255-x)
    alpha = gradient.resize(im.size)
    black_im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=0) # i.e. black
    black_im.putalpha(alpha)
    gradient_im = Image.alpha_composite(im, black_im)
    gradient_im.save('out.png', 'PNG')
```

## EDIT

There are different ways to scale the gradient. Below is one suggestion.

```
def test(path, gradient_magnitude=1.):
    im = Image.open(path)
    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
        im = im.convert('RGBA')
    width, height = im.size
    gradient = Image.new('L', (width, 1), color=0xFF)
    for x in range(width):
        # gradient.putpixel((x, 0), 255-x)
        gradient.putpixel((x, 0), int(255 * (1 - gradient_magnitude * float(x)/width)))
    alpha = gradient.resize(im.size)
    black_im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=0) # i.e. black
    black_im.putalpha(alpha)
    gradient_im = Image.alpha_composite(im, black_im)
    gradient_im.save('out.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: Thanks. It's seems works. But how can I control gradient size? I don't need gradient on full image size.

Comment: Sorry, i skipped gradient_magnitude, seems it's ok, I should play with it more. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe do you know. How can I add more opacity? Just on left side it is very black.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want a gradient with dark grey instead of black? In either case, you should open a new question for a new issue.

Comment: You are right. New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976028/python-pillow-make-gradient-for-transparency