# How to create different transparency like gradient with python pil?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Can I do something like this with python pillow? Don't know how to describe it.

[image]

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842286/python-pillow-add-transparent-gradient-to-an-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pillow: Add transparent gradient to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842286/python-pillow-add-transparent-gradient-to-an-image)

Comment: I would prefer if I could use RGB or HEX. I would like to change colors, I don't know how to do with RGBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

This is easier than my original answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Define width and height
w, h = 400, 200

# Make solid orange background
im = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), 'orange')

# Build an alpha/transparency channel
alpha = Image.linear_gradient('L').rotate(-90).resize((w,h))
alpha.save('DEBUG-alpha.png')

# Put our lovely new alpha channel into orange image
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Here is how the alpha channel looks - I have added a red border so you can see its extent on any background:

[image]

If you want to change the roll-off rate between orange and transparency, you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height
w, h = 400, 200

# Make solid orange background
im = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), 'orange')

# Build an alpha/transparency channel
alpha = Image.linear_gradient('L').rotate(-90).resize((w,h))

# Optional gamma adjustment. Smaller gamma makes image darker, bigger gamma makes it brighter
gamma = 0.4
alpha = alpha.point(lambda f: int((f/255.0)**(1/gamma)*255))
alpha.save('DEBUG-alpha.png')

# Put our lovely new alpha channel into orange image
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]
[image]

**Original Answer**

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Define width and height
w, h = 400, 200

# Make solid orange background
im = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), 'orange')

# Build an alpha/transparency channel
# ... make one line w pixels wide, going from 255..0
line = np.linspace(255,0, num=w, dtype=np.uint8)
# ... repeat that line h times to get the full height of the image
alpha = np.tile(line, (h,1))

# Put our lovely new alpha channel into orange image
im.putalpha(Image.fromarray(alpha))

im.save('result.png')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Good luck with your project.